# How to "hide" private classes/members/methods from a jar like android.jar

Tags: jar, hide, private

I'm working on releasing a SDK package.
I don't want the developers who use my package to see any private elements when they add the jar to their eclipse projects.

I studied the android.jar. It just hides any private class/method/member.

How can I do like that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a way to obfuscate your code.

> [...] Automated bytecode obfuscation makes reverse-engineering a program difficult and economically unfeasible. Other advantages could include helping to protect licensing mechanisms and unauthorized access, hiding vulnerabilities and shrinking the size of the executable.
>   [Bytecode obfuscation - Owasp wiki](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Bytecode_obfuscation)

The wiki includes an example of using such a tool.